# How to pass a string into the object method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object method `a` like below:

```
var f = {
   a: function(e){
       e.call();
       console.log(t);    // Here should print “Hello world”
   }
};
f.a(function(){
    f.a.t = "Hello world";
    // How to pass the string “Hello world” into the object method “a” ?
});
```

`e` is an anonymous function. I call the `e` and now I want to pass a string `Hello world` into the object method `a`. If it's not allowed to use global variable, how can I pass the string into the object method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `e` in the context of `f` then you would need to pass `f` to `call`, writing `e.call()` would be equal to `e()`.

Beside that `t` refers to a variable and not to the property `t` of `a`. You cannot set a variable that way, but you could store it in the object `f`

You would write it that way.

```
var f = {
   a: function(e){
       e.call(this);
       console.log(this.t);
   }
};
f.a(function(){
    this.t = "Hello world";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider to change the return value of your `e`as below:

```js
    var f = {
       a: function(e){
           var t = e.call();//here declare variable t
           console.log(t);    // Here should print “Hello world”
       }
    };
    f.a(function(){
        return "Hello world";//directly return string value from anonymous function
        // How to pass the string “Hello world” into the object method “a” ?
    });
```

Comment: Very elegant. This solution nicely decouples the declaration of `f` and the anonymous function: you don't have to know the inner working of `f` in the anonymous function. In the other solutions -including the one I proposed- the anonymous function has to know that, in order to pass the string `"Hello world"`, it has to set the value of the attribute `t` of object `f` or `this` (in which case, if you forget to add `this` to `e.call()`, it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

See below snippet

```js
var f = {
   a: function(e){
       e.call();
       console.log(f.a.t);    // Here should print “Hello world”
   }
};
f.a(function(){
    f.a.t = "Hello world";
    // How to pass the string “Hello world” into the object method “a” ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `t`'s scope? If it's an attribute of `f`, write this:

```
var f = {
    a: function(e){
        e.call();
        console.log(this.t); // this line changed
    }
};
f.a(function(){
    f.t = "Hello world"; // this line changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a property in object like:

```js
var f = {
  t: '',
  a: function(e){
    e.call();
    console.log(this.t);    // Here should print “Hello world”
  }
};
f.a(function(){
    f.t = "Hello world";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

f is java script object and you can add property to that.I just added f.t="Hello world".you can use f.t anywhere in programme wherever you have f scope.

```
var f = {
       a: function(e){
           e.call();
           console.log(f.t);    // Here should print “Hello world”
       }
    };
    f.a(function(){
        f.t = "Hello world";
        // How to pass the string “Hello world” into the object method “a” ?
    });
```